# How to create a custom Kivy Label Class with formatting in python?

Tags: python, formatting, label, kivy

I'm writing a desktop app using kivy but it doesn't run as fast as I would like it to. I have many labels and buttons with lots of formatting which only differ in colour and size. I hope that if I create a custom kivy Label with the formatting already on it will improve performance. I have already all my labels with the formatting and I wish to change them all to my custom kivy Label.

### The original code in kivy file. Here is how all my labels look like.

```
Label:  
    text: "some text"  
    color: (0, 0.2, .4, 1)  
    size_hint: 1, 0.04  
    text_size: self.size  
    halign: 'left'  
    valign: 'top'  
    bold: True  
    canvas.before:  
        Color:  
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1  
        Rectangle:  
            pos: self.pos  
            size: self.size
```

So I tried to create a FormattedLabel class to add to it all the formatting I wanted and then just change my Label for FormattedLabel in the kivy file.

### Python file

```
import kivy  
from kivy.app import App  

from kivy.uix.label import Label  
from kivy.properties import ListProperty  
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle  
from kivy.lang import Builder  

with open("crea_kivy_file.kv", encoding='utf8') as f: 
    Builder.load_string(f.read())  

class FormattedLabel(Label):  
    background_color = ListProperty()  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        Label.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)  
        self.canvas.add(Color(self.background_color))  
        self.canvas.add(Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size))  
        self.text_size= self.size  
        self.halign= 'left'  
        self.valign= 'top'  
        self.bold= True
```

### Kivy file

```
FormattedLabel:  
    text: "some text"  
    color: (0, 0.2, .4, 1)  
    size_hint: 1, 0.04  
    background_color: 0,0,0,1
```

But it didn't produce the same results as my original code: 
1. The size of the rectangle is off (narrower and taller) so the letters do not longer fit in a straight line. I don't know how to bind the rectangle's size to the size_hint in the kivy file. 
2. The colour of the label doesn't change. 
I don't know if it is because the code should not be under **init** or because I'm just not getting how to write it properly. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: "But it didn't produce the same results as my original code." <- so, what's different? The obvious thing to me is that your Rectangle won't have the right size and pos because when you add it in python you just set it to the current pos/size which aren't yet fully initialised (probably pos 0,0 and size 100,100), whereas when you did it in kv this would automatically create a binding to update to the initialised values. But, I don't know if this is the difference you're asking about.

Comment: Sorry for being unspecific! Yes, the rectangle doesn't have the right size but also the canvas color doesn't change, it is always white.

Comment: I think your problem is that when you do `Widget` properties in `Python`, you don't get the additional capabilities that doing the same in `kv` produces. In your `__init__()` method of `FormattedLabel`, the values used for `size`, `pos`,  and `background_color` are those at the time the `__init__()` method is executed, and any changes to those properties will have no effect (and all those properties are changed after `__init__`). You can set up bindings to reflect changes in those properties (which is what `kv` does for you).

Answer (score 0):

## Problems

> 1. The size of the rectangle is off (narrower and taller) so the letters do not longer fit in a straight line. I don't know how to bind
>      the rectangle's size to the size_hint in the kivy file.
> 2. The colour of the label doesn't change. I don't know if it is because the code should not be under init or because I'm just not
>      getting how to write it properly.

### Root Cause

The result is not as expected because Kivy has not completed its styling. For example, the size of the rectangle is off because it is using the default size of a widget i.e (100, 100).

> The [`load_kv()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv) function is called from [run()](http://This%20function%20is%20called%20from%20run(),%20therefore,), therefore,
>   any widget whose styling is defined in this kv file and is created
>   before [run()](http://This%20function%20is%20called%20from%20run(),%20therefore,) is called (e.g. in `__init__`), won’t have its styling
>   applied. Note that [build()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.build) is called after [load_kv](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv) has been
>   called.

## Solution

1. Implement a method, `initialize_widget()`
2. Replace `canvas.add` with `canvas.before.add` because without the `before` keyword, the text will not be visible.
3. Use Kivy Clock [`schedule_once()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.CyClockBase.schedule_once) method to invoke the `initialize_widget()` function after Kivy completed styling.

### Snippets

```
from kivy.clock import Clock

...

class FormattedLabel(Label):  
    background_color = ListProperty()  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        Label.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)  
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.initialize_widget(), 0.002)

    def initialize_widget(self):
        self.canvas.before.add(Color(self.background_color))  
        self.canvas.before.add(Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size))  
        self.text_size = self.size  
        self.halign = 'left'  
        self.valign = 'top'  
        self.bold = True
```